# How to get other parameter's bound model in ModelBinder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

My controller's action accepts two parameters, each having a custom `ModelBinder`:

```cs
public ActionResult MyAction(
    [ModelBinder(typeof(FooBinder))] Foo foo,
    [ModelBinder(typeof(BarBinder))] Bar bar)
```

Is there a way to access the `foo` instance in the `BarBinder`?

Answer (score 0):

I had to resort to a cooperative use-aware mode in which `FooBinder` shares its `foo` instance for `BarBinder` via `controllerContext.Controller.TempData` dictionary.